# How do I get the iOS/tvOS run script for FirebaseCrashlytics(beta) to work?

Tags: xcode, firebase, crashlytics, circleci

I'm using the following run script:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p tvos "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

It stalls when it runs in CircleCI. When I try to run the first part locally I get `error: Could not get platform name from build environment`. How do I pass this information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -p ios, since Firebase does not have platform support for tvOS/macOS, yet.

Comment: What if I run `./CrashlyticsScripts/run -gsp My-app/Analytics/GoogleService-Info_QA.plist -p ios ./dSYMs` and I get this same error? I provide `-p ios` and the path to the dsyms, but it doesn't seem to help.. (I double checked and the paths are correct for my case)

Comment: In the end it worked. We had to move Firebase accounts recently and the "Crashlytics dashboard" wasn't unlocked yet. Apparently the "add SDK" step has to be done before Firebase accepts any dSYM uploads.